# Can I pass a lock object by reference?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, recursion, locking

I have a recursive function that spawns several async tasks.  Each task updates a common dictionary object.

Is it OK for me to share the lock object with the other threads as a parameter in the function?

```
public class RecursiveTest
{ 

   void DoRecursiveWork(ref object myDictLock, dictionary<string,string> myDict)
   {
    // yadda.. async code that calls DoRecursiveWork()

   }

}
```

Comment: What happens when you try it?

Comment: i don't see why you couldn't, but this somehow strikes me as a bad design. who's responsible for locking or unlocking? what if one function forgets to release the lock?

Comment: @Mark The function DoRecursiveWork will always lock and release the lock before exiting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that you are planning to do something like this

```
// do something
lock (myDictLock) {
    // access the dictionary
}
// do something else
```

you can pass your object "by reference" or by "value" (that is, by reference to the reference or by value of the reference, because `object` is a reference type). In both cases locking on the object is going to work. When you pass by reference, you'll be able to assign the variable passed at the top of the recursive chain, too, although I doubt that that is what you are planning to do.

Comment: +1. It does indeed sounds very strange to wish to change lock object separately from object one wants to protect.

Comment: I would like to have 3 instances of my recursion function run in different threads at the same time. That means I'll need 3 instances of a lock and dictionary that will be called many time.  Do you see any issue with this design?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I've seen many recommendations on MSDN and SO to use dedicated Lock objects that are not the actual variable I am using.  I've adopted the convention of variableName+Lock for this

Comment: My plan is to move the variables from the function level to the class level.  I'll then create a new RecursiveTest class and allow the recursion to happen from there.

Comment: @makerofthings7 I think that keeping the variables at the function level was an equally good plan, although a dedicated `RecursiveTest` class would work fine too.

Comment: @makerofthings7, It still does not explain why would you need "ref" - you want pair of objects to be created and at the same time and never re-created separately. "ref" implies that your method is going to change what variable points to - in your case signature of `DoRecursiveWork` method says "whatever variable passed as `myDictLock` argument will be (sometimes) updated (contains another object as result), `myDict` may be populated". As result whoever calls the function should expect multiple objects created for myDictLock and only one myDict.